# php: how to cut and paste line within file

Tags: php, csv

I want to search a file and make sure every row does not begin with a non-numeric character or whitespace.  If it does, I want to remove line and append it to previous line (because it actually is an error with the file processing...)

Input:

```
29034985
491017
 Contact us at info@
19403935
```

Output:

```
29034985
491017 Contact us at info@
19403935
```

My code that does this:

```
while (($data = fgetcsv('/tmp/file.tsv', 1000, "\t")) !== FALSE) {
    if (is_numeric($data[0])){}
    else
      # do the processing here!
```

Any tips on how to do this?  Does php have a cut/paste-like function?

Comment: it's work-work, hence the many bugs with file processing :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get all content and replace using preg_replace

```
$data = file_get_contents('/tmp/file.tsv');
$data = preg_replace('#\n([a-zA-z].+)\n#', ' $1\n', $data);

# Write the data to a new file or to the same file
```

Comment: thanks for sharing the preg_replace() function! which function that is least memory intensive do you recomment for writing to the same file?

Comment: Yeah you can write it to the same file using `file_put_contents`

Comment: just want to clarify what the # sign is matching in the regex?

Comment: Its not matching anything. Its, say the regex boundary. Usually we use `/`, and the regex will be like `/your_regex/`. You can use another symbols like `@,*,#,....` too.

Comment: final question, do you also know a easy way to remove leading whitespaces? `$data = preg_replace('#\n([a-zA-z].+)\n#', ' $1\n', trim($data));` ?

Comment: Where are you getting the leading whitespace characters. Actually your input doesn't have that and the regex is written in that assumption. Also I have put a leading space in the replacement `' $1\n'`, is that you are referring?

Comment: I just edited the question input, sorry just found this new 'bug'

Comment: Please try `$data = preg_replace('#\n\s*([a-zA-z].+)\n#', ' $1\n', $data);`

Comment: Hmm this doesn't match lines beginning with hyphen '-', I tried just adding it: `preg_replace('#\n\s*([a-zA-z-].+)\n#', ' $1\n', $data);` but it doesn't yield right results.. is hyphen a special regex char?

Comment: @user1899415 : I think it has to work. Try escaping it using `\`, and so it will become `\n\s*([a-zA-z\-].+)\n`

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is -

1. Read File
2. Process Data
3. Write back to the file

Try this...

```
$counter = 0;
$csv_data = array();
while (($data = fgetcsv('/tmp/file.tsv', 1000, "\t")) !== FALSE) {
    if (is_numeric($data[0])) {
        $csv_data[$counter] = $data[0];
        $counter++;
    } else {
        $csv_data[$counter] .= ' '. $data[0];
    }
}

$fp = fopen('/tmp/file.tsv', 'w');
foreach ($csv_data as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: thanks for this! I was hoping for a more efficient way than writing again to a file. But if there's no other way, then just have to make do

Comment: I don't think there is another way to do so.